# How to add icons to the listview in windows Forms c#

Tags: c#, listview

How to add an icon to the listView in Windows Forms c#? I have found a NuGet called "ObjectListView" but I don't understand how to add items and sub-items to it. By using standard listview I am able to add images to the first column only.

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

            item.ImageIndex = 0;

            this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

I'm trying to add buttons to remove/restart/etc. for USB devices like this [MyProgram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rucLq.png)

I need those buttons/Images in "remove", "Restart, "Uninstall" columns as subitems.

By using this I can "switch" columns, but still cannot add images/buttons for multiple columns.

```
 listView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 1;
      //  listView1.Items.Add("tekst3", 3);
       // listView1.Items.Add("tekst2", 2);
        //listView1.Items.Add("tekst1", 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)

        {

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

            item.ImageIndex = 0;

            this.listView1.Items.Add(item);

        }
```

An image list is added with loaded files(3 of them) attached to the list view small/large image list.

Comment: do you have an ImageList?

Comment: Yes. I added it to listview - small icons and large icons. This will add images only to the first column. I need 3 last columns at all.

Comment: Why you don't show the way you added them?

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 1;
          //  listView1.Items.Add("tekst3", 3);
           // listView1.Items.Add("tekst2", 2);
            //listView1.Items.Add("tekst1", 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)

            {

                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

                item.ImageIndex = 0;

                this.listView1.Items.Add(item);

            }

Comment: This will put it to 3rd column, but still cannot add buttons to the next columns

Comment: Thanks, you can  insert it in your aswer for easy reading.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the image list

```
listView1.SmallImageList = imageList;

    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++ )
    {
      
            listView1.Items[i].ImageIndex =i;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The image list was already assigned: [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGRnE.png)
Your code will add image to the first row only. The difference is that I have to click a specific item in the first column.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                listView1.Items[i].ImageIndex = i;

            }

        }
```

This will give the following result:[Click1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhlYd.png)
I need it like this: [Click2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVOsc.png)

**EDIT** This what you write is not what I mean. I Have found the solution:

```
private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // insert buttons to last two columns
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), e.Bounds);
        }

        else if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, 60, 20);
            //  e.Graphics.DrawImage(SystemIcons.Information.ToBitmap(), imageRect);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Resources.Remove_PNG, imageRect);
        }
        else
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So if this is wrong how I should do this?